Does Nash Equilibrium say anything about odds?
Edited after good comment from @lulu
I'm struggling with the concept of a Nash Equilibrium.
I'm getting confused by comparing the prisoners dilemma with a game like rock-paper-scissors. The prisoners dilemma is often brought into the picture as an example why both parties will choose to rat each other out. This makes total sense. One choice leads to another and they both end up in the top left corner.
But the Nash Equilibrium of rock paper scissors is different. It is accepted that the Nash equilibrium is a random choice between the 3 options.
So what if rock only beats paper nine out of ten times, the other rules still apply. And let's assume that both players know about all the rules and the dominant position of the rock vs the rest. Can the nash equilibrium then be calculated as follows?:
rock rock - 0.5    scis rock - 0        pape rock - 0.9
rock scis - 1      scis scis - 0.5      pape scis - 0
rock pape - 0.1    scis pape - 1        pape pape - 0.5
____________________________________________________________________________+
            1.6                 1,5                 1,4

Pick (in a completely random way):
Rock 1.6/4,5 of the time
Scissors 1,5/4,5 of the time.
Paper 1.4/4.5 of the time.

Not entirely sure what you are asking.  The Nash equilibrium for rock-paper-scissors is $\frac 13$ probability for each.  If you used different probabilities, then you'd favor one option over the others, and your opponent would bet on whatever beats that option accordingly.  That would force you to change and, eventually, to drift into equilibrium.

I see, that indeed confirms the things I read. My mistake was that I thought that you needed do 'end up' at this strategy by looping over different possibilities, which often happens to explain the prisoners dilemma, but that is not a requirement.
Would you say my calculation of the 'advanced rock' variation is also correct then?

I don't understand your proposed equilibrium.  $\frac 2{3.5}+\frac {1.5}{3.5}+\frac 1{3.5}>1$.  Or have I misread your numbers?

woops you are right, it should be 4.5 instead of 3.5! I'll change that immediately. Is it correct then? Or what would the correct solution be in this case?

Why write it like that? Isn't $\frac 49, \frac 39, \frac 29$ simpler?

But...why do you think that's an equilibrium?  Not sure I see one.  All $R$ vs all $P$ looks good...$\frac 12$ for both sides.  And the Paper player can't improve.  But, the Rock player can start to play $S$ from time to time and thereby improves, which of course will cause the Paper player to shift.

The strategy you pick...if I play all $R$, I win everytime you play $S$ and half the time you play $P$, so I win with probability $\frac 39+\frac 19=\frac 49$.   Wheras if I play $S$ only, I win only if you play $P$, so $\frac 29$ chance, and if I play $P$ I win with probability $\frac 29$.  So I do better if I start to play $R$ more and more, which will encourage you to play Scissors less, and so on.

You are right... maybe this is a bad example. Let me edit it but fully acknowledge your point here!

The key difference is that in the prisoner’s dilemma, there is an outcome with greater total utility assuming cooperation.
As you probably already know, if either agent deviates from this cooperation outcome then they are better off for themselves. Suppose you could be certain that your opponent would not ‘rat’ you out, what is your best response? Obviously to rat them out, but if your opponent knows that you will rat them out then their best response is to also rat you out.
In the game of rock, paper, scissors or even your adjusted game, there is no payout structure in place where cooperation would provide greater total utility to both players; hence it is in every player’s best interest to only play in such a way that they are not exploitable by their opponent. This is a zero-sum game.

Thanks for replying. It is an interesting distinction!
Curious what do you think about my question (in bold)? Even in a zero-sum games there can be Nash equilibria right? So is my nash equilibrium valid?

@Cdl see the answer Alex gave below

As I understand, the Nash equilibrium requires to provide (mixed) strategies for both players,
whereas you provided only the strategy for the column player. But by the symmetry the row player can use the same optimal strategy that the first player.
But the strategy which you proposed is not optimal. Indeed, if the matrix entries are equal to the gain of the row player then the scissors choice provides him the expected gain $\frac {16}{45}\cdot 1+\frac {15}{45}\cdot 0.5+\frac {14}{45}\cdot 0=\frac{235}{450}>0.5$ and if the matrix entries are equal to the gain of the column player then the rock choice of the row player provides him the expected gain $1-\left(\frac {16}{45}\cdot 0.5+\frac {15}{45}\cdot 0+\frac {14}{45}\cdot 0.9\right)=\frac{244}{450}>0.5$.

Thank you so much for answering Alex! Hmmm OK so you say the equilibrium is void because player A would still like to switch once it knows that the other one is always picking the top choice. So how would you find this nash equilibrium then?
Can we conclude that any nash equilibrium involving chance that favors one and a system where one choice beats the other (so no heads/tails with a weighted coin) is non existent? No... because I know that these are found in poker, which is exactly this.
